# Create nested object to new object

Tags: javascript, object, nested

Im trying to create a new object with the exact same structure (keys, values) to a new object. Im almost there but having problem with the nested part in the new object.

Im stuck at where I need to check if the new nested object already have a object assigned to it. As it is now I overwrite the nested object part. Im not sure how to solve this part. I would appreciate some insight how to solve this.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u758px3h/

My code:

```
const interests = [{'name': 'Tennis', 'date': new Date('2019-05-12')}, {'name': 'Golf', 'date': new Date('2019-12-12')}];
const person = {'id': 82, 'name': 'John', 'interests': interests};

let newObject = {};
function test(object, key) {
  Object.keys(object).map((objectKey) => {
    if (typeof(object[objectKey]) === 'object' && !(object[objectKey] instanceof Date)) {
      Object.keys(object[objectKey]).map((innerKey) => {
        test(object[objectKey][innerKey], objectKey);
      });
    } else {
        if (key !== undefined) {
        if (newObject[key] === undefined) {
            newObject[key] = [];
        }
        newObject[key][objectKey] = object[objectKey];
      } else {
        newObject[objectKey] = object[objectKey];
      }
    }
  });
  return newObject;
}

console.log(test(person));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest such code to copy objects

```
const interests = [{'name': 'Tennis', 'date': new Date('2019-05-12')}, {'name': 'Golf', 'date': new Date('2019-12-12')}];
const person = {'id': 82, 'name': 'John', 'interests': interests};

function copyObject(object, objectsMap = []) {
  // lets copy object
  const newObject = Array.isArray(object) ? [...object] : { ...object}

  // iterate each property to check if it is object or not
  for (let key in newObject) {
    const value = newObject[key]
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null && !(value instanceof Date)) {
      let newValue
      // check in objectsMap was the same object copied before
      const createdObject = objectsMap.find(v => v.oldObject === value)
      if (createdObject) { // if yes then just assign created before object
        newValue = createdObject.newObject
      } else { // if no then copy this object and add to objectsMap
        newValue = copyObject(value, objectsMap)
        objectsMap.push({ oldObject: value, newObject: newValue})
      }
      // assign newValue to current key
      newObject[key] = newValue
    } 
  }
  return newObject
}

const newInterests = copyObject(interests)
console.log(newInterests)
```

Comment: Thank you, very nice solution!